# Event Handler Sequence

Tags: asp.net

I have a piece of test code in order to understand the executing sequence of event handlers. Why is the sequence like this?:

1. `Button1_Init`
2. `Page_Init`
3. `Page_Load`
4. `Button1_Load`
5. `Page_PreRender`
6. `Button1_PreRender`
7. `Button1_Unload`
8. `Page_Unload`

For example, why is `Button1_Init` before `Page_Init`, but `Page_Load` is before `Button1_Load`?

The test code:

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Page_Disposed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Page_Unload(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_Disposed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_Unload(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: And this is the exact reason I hate ASP.Net. Why even bother with it, move to ASP.Net MVC

Comment: you should use this for reference http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: The PreInit is before the Init of the controls, and in the same order as the rest. Web forms is just fine and you can make anything fast and easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Page_Init gets fired when all controls will gets initialized to make sure the all control gets initialized before page is going to add/use them else null reference will occur.
2. this time page need to set the various properties of the controls that is why the load of page get fired first and then button load is getting fired .

The same things happens for the prerender.

One more tip : Preinit in userControl is not available.It is available in page only as control does not exist yet.